# CString.Format insert slash

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

I'm getting crazy  tring to understand why second example doesn't work...

```
CString _slashes;

  CString _path;

  _slashes = _T("\\");


  _path.Format(_T("AA\\BB"));      // WORKS

  _path.Format(_T("AA"),_slashes,_T("BB"),_slashes);      // NOT WORK!
```

The purpose to paramtreize slash character is be able to set '\' or '/'
How I can insert a '\' character in CString?

Tnks!

Comment: This is not the way to use `Format()`. Please consult [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa314327.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CString::Format` takes a `printf`-style format string, so you could use:

```
_path.Format("%s%s%s%s", _T("AA"), _slashes, _T("BB"), _slashes);
```

Edit:

It has been asserted that this would be better written as:

```
_path.Format("%s%s%s%s", _T("AA"), (LPCTSTR)_slashes., _T("BB"), (LPCTSTR)_slashes);
```

While this makes no difference in practice, there's some room for argument that it adds a degree of safety that's lacking without the casts.

Alternatively, you could just concatenate the pieces together, something like:

```
_path = _T("AA");
_path += _slashes;
_path += _T("BB");
_path += _slashes;
```

If I were doing this, I'd probably use [`Boost FileSystem`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm), which already provides a `make_preferred` that will convert a path to using the native path separators (e.g., will convert `AA/BB` to `AA\BB` if your running it on Windows).

Comment: Same mistake here: You are passing a `CString` object where a `const TCHAR*` is expected. This is code-by-coincidence.

Comment: @IInspectable: Quite the contrary. Back when these things were new, Microsoft made quite a big deal about designing `CString` so this type of usage would work and was supported. Your comment reflects only your own lack of knowledge, not anything about the code (though the comment *would* be fair about almost any other class).

Comment: I **do** know, that `CString` is hacked together, to only hold a single member: `XCHAR* m_pszData;`. Passing a `CString` object to a `%s` format specifier, however, is neither documented to work, nor guaranteed. It's a coincidence, no more. `CString::GetString()`, on the other hand, is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k59cayc6.aspx).

Comment: @IInspectable: Yes, it *is* documented (or used to be, anyway).

Comment: If you are **that** sure, it would be easy for you to post the documentation. Makes you wonder, why you haven't. Fact is, it isn't documented. `CString` is designed to work in the real world, where developers blindly throw `CString`s at anything that asks for a `const TCHAR*`. It is not meant to be abused this way. Use the cast operator, or `GetString()`. Anyway, find the documentation or stop spreading dangerous practices.

Comment: @IInspectable: On what basis do you claim it's not documented, since you've obviously never actually looked at MSDN at all (otherwise you'd already *know* that finding it could take hours).

Comment: What's with the rudeness and all? I asked you to provide documentation you claimed would exist. I doubt it does. I also doubt that I never actually looked. After all, I did find [`CStringT::Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18he3sk6.aspx): *"Writes formatted data to a CStringT in the same way that sprintf_s formats data into a C-style character array."* Now... it would be somewhat surprising, if `sprintf_s` would even **mention** `CString`, considering that it doesn't even know of its existence. Now if you want to prove me wrong, keep it civil.

Comment: I don't care a bit about proving you wrong. You're the one claiming that the answer is wrong, but failing to provide any proof (or even support) for your claim.

Comment: I provided the link to the documentation. No mention of special guarantees for `CString` with the `%s` format specifier. How do you propose to prove that something does **not** exist? I mean, seriously... You, however, have the easy part. Since you claim this particular piece of documentation exists, just link to it. I cannot believe how dense grumpy old people can get.

Comment: @IInspectable: You're still the one making the assertion, and therefore bear the burden of proof. The fact that you've chosen to assert something you can't prove doesn't change that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42605/discussion-between-iinspectable-and-jerry-coffin)

Comment: The documentation for [`CString::Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa314327.aspx) (referring to `CString` prior to the merge with ATL) has the following to say: *"When you pass a character string as an optional argument, you **must** cast it explicitly as LPCTSTR."* (emphasis theirs)

Comment: You point to documentation you know full well is out of date, yet you claim *I'm* the one being dense here?

Comment: Whether the documentation is out of date or not cannot be answered. The question doesn't specify which version of the `CString` is in use. I also linked to up-to-date documentation, which apparently wasn't good enough for you either. Why not simply accept the facts instead of talking back nonsense?

Comment: Well, glancing at the docs, nearly the first thing I find is: "CString objects also have the following characteristics: [...]You can freely substitute CString objects for const char* and LPCTSTR function arguments."

Comment: Important point being: **Function arguments** (of type x and y), this refers to **formal** parameters, with a type. This does **not** refer to optional arguments, passed to the ellipsis.

Comment: And yet, that's not what it actually says. It specifically says "function arguments", not "arguments to functions with formal parameters of type..." IOW, it's specifically saying you can substitute a CString *anywhere* you could pass a `char const *`. Bottom line: you're trying to read "arguments" as "parameters", which is just plain wrong.

Comment: It says *"for const char\* and LPCTSTR arguments"*. It states the **types**, and thereby refers **only** to typed formal parameters. This is safe, since it invokes the cast-operator. This does not happen when a `CString` is passed to the ellipsis. IOW, it's **not** safe to pass a `CString` anywhere a `const char*` is **expected**, unless it is specifically typed.

Comment: @IInspectable: Nonsense. It says for arguments. That does not in any way imply typed formal parmeters. If I call `printf("%d", 10);`, `10` is most certainly an argument of type `int`. The fact that there's no formal parameter to specify that type is utterly irrelevant.

Comment: I provided a rationale for why my interpretation is correct. If that is not enough, then maybe [CString Operations Relating to C-Style Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awkwbzyc.aspx) is: *"It is essential that you use an explicit type cast when passing a CString object to a function that takes a variable number of arguments."* This is official documentation, up-to-date as well, as requested.

Answer (score 2):

That's not how `Format` works.
Try this instead:

```
_path.Format (_T ("AA%sBB%s"), (LPCTSTR)_slashes, (LPCTSTR)_slashes)
```

This probably isn't the best way to handle slashes though and you shouldn't start your variable names with an underline.

If you are using MFC, then your application is pretty much Windows-only. Most Windows commands are okay with forward-slashes, but I would just stick to back-slashes instead.

Comment: You are passing `CString` objects where `const TCHAR*` are expected. Like everyone else, apparently. This should be `_path.Format( _T( "AA%sBB%s" ), _slashes.GetString(), _slashes.GetString() );`.

Comment: I've never had a problem doing it like this, but [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa314327%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) seems to agree with you. Were you the down-voter?

Comment: I did downvote the answer as initially posted. The downvote has been removed now that the answer has been corrected. I would still favor calling `GetString()` over a cast. Casting should be kept to a minimum, and only be used when there is a convincing reason.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry.. there was a lot of time that I not program in C++ xD

```
  _path.Format(_T("AA%sBB%s"),_slashes,_slashes);   // This works!
```

Comment: No, it doesn't. It produces the expected result, by pure coincidence and luck. `%s` expects a pointer to a `const TCHAR`. You are passing a `CString` object.